# How to efficiently query in eloquent through a belongsTo relationship by actually using the relationship definition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

In Eloquent the only documented way I've found to query through a belongsTo relationship by using the relationship definition is by using `whereHas`, which is implemented as a subquery and thus cannot be properly optimized by the mysql engine in order to use the join buffer and causes temporary tables to be created which makes this very inefficient for large data sets.

The efficient way to query this kinds of relationships in mysql is through joins, but I have found no way to generate actual joins by using the relation definitions in eloquent.

**Is there a way to generate a query like this without manually joining the tables?** (which defeats the purpose of defining the relationship in eloquent....):

```
SELECT b.* FROM model_b_items b 
    INNER JOIN model_a_items a ON b.a_id = a.id 
    WHERE a.somefield = 'somevalue'
```

Just to clarify, an eloquent belongsTo relatinship for this example would be like:

```
class ModelBItem extends Model{
    ....
    function a(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelAItem::class, 'a_id');
    }
    ...
}
```

The only documented way with whereHas looks like this:

```
ModelBItems::whereHas('a', function($q){
    $q->where('somefield', 'somevalue');
});
```

But this generates a subquery instead of a join, like this:

```
SELECT b.* FROM model_b_items b WHERE (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM model_a_items a 
         WHERE b.a_id = a.id AND a.somefield = 'somevalue'
   ) > 0
```

By defeating the purpose of defining the relationship, this can be solved as follows, but what is the point of defining the relationship if the joins cannot be inferred by eloquent?

```
ModelBItems::select('model_b_items.*')
->join('model_a_items', 'model_b_items.a_id', '=', 'model_b_items.id')
->where('model_a_items.somefield', 'somevalue');
```

What I'm looking for is to have eloquent internally infer the table name "model_b_items" and the condition `'model_b_items.a_id', '=', 'model_a_items.id'`. Like this (which doesn't work):

```
ModelBItems::where('a.somefield','somevalue');
```

Otherwise, why have the relationship definition at all if I'm going to be repeating the join condition and the table names on every non trivial query?

Comment: The default behaviour for Laravel relationships is to not use any kind of `join()`s, but rather a separate query; i.e. `ModelAItems::with('model_b_items')->find(1)` would execute `SELECT * FROM model_a_items WHERE id = 1;` and `SELECT * FROM model_b_items WHERE a_id IN (1)`. Also, Laravel does infer the names when you use a matching model/relationship name, like `ModelBItems`, and `public function model_b_items()`. I believe there is a packages that override this behaviour, using `join` instead, but you'll have to search for that.

Comment: "laravel relationship joins", 3rd result on Google: https://github.com/tylernathanreed/laravel-relation-joins. (I didn't downvote btw, quite the opposite). A typical reason for downvotes is asking for libraries/packages, so maybe that's why? Although you didn't directly ask for one, I suggested it...  TBH I don't see a reason for that downvote.

Comment: Thanks! , It actually never crossed my mind to look for external packages for this mainly because I believed it was handled natively somehow and I just didn't know how. I also usually prefer to solve things without external libraries where possible. Why don't you post that as an answer? If the package does the thing, then that's the answer isn't it?

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help :) I probably won't post that as an answer, as if I were to write it, it would at best be a link-only answer. You can leave this question open, and after implementing that package, add a self-answer showing some example usage, or simply leave this open and see if someone else knows of a way to modify it without a package. Alternatively, you can delete this question, but ultimately it's all up to you :) Cheers!